# Facebook Graph API Explorer and iOS SDK API call return different results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, hybrid-mobile-app

The Graph API Explorer always returns bunch of results (events that me and my friends are attending), but the SDK query always returns an empty set.

I am using the iOS Facebook SDK on a hybrid mobile app (Phonegap with Facebook plugin - this plugin yields the connection to the native SDK).

It's the same FQL query in both places, here is my js code:

```
  FB.api('/fql?q=' +
    encodeURIComponent([
      "SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event",
      "WHERE eid IN (",
         "SELECT eid FROM event_member",
         "WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())  OR uid = me())",
      ")",
      "AND start_time > now()",
      "LIMIT 50"
    ].join(" ")),
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log("Error fetching data.");
        } else {
            events = response.data;
            console.log(events);
            displayEvents(events);
        }
    }
  );
```

My facebook app requires `user_events` and `friend_events` permissions (I tried to add user_friends permission, but after I save it and refresh - it's always gone from the list...perhaps these are given by default and don't need to be specified?).

Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: did you tried removing `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: The query is in the URL - it has to be encoded. Anyways, for sanity check I did tried it and, of course, the service doesn't get the full query (everything after the first space) and returns "unexpected end of query.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Facebook's client SDK should request the permissions on user's login.

The permissions should be set in the cloud & then requested on login from your client. Here is the login:

```
FB.login(callback, {scope: 'user_events,friends_events'});
```

I personally think this is confusing (especially naming the parameter "scope"), but that's the rules.